# Database with multiple values for the same ID

Tags: sql, database, excel

I have a database where each entity has a unique ID, but recently all of the entity names were changed (not in the same way) to improve readability. These changes aren't standard across the different names and vary from ID to ID.  This has made a lot of the summary reports look like the following:

```
ID     Name            Total for the year     
3011   Joesmith          3000
3011   Joe Smith         1000
5024   DBS               400
5024   Deborah Smith     150
```

The individual rows might look something like:

```
ID     Name          Transaction      Date
3011   Joesmith      2000             January 1, 2017   
3011   Joesmith      1000             January 2, 2017   
3011   Joe Smith     500              February 1, 2017
3011   Joe Smith     500              February 5, 2017
```

What's the best way of going about either correcting the old entries to match the new ones or simply displaying the new name for any matching ID?  At the end of the day we can get the summaries we're interested in by just using the ID's, but ultimately we want to interpret those by seeing our names.

We're looking at about 1000 or so IDs with different names and maybe 50,000 or so rows in total.

Comment: You mention "database", so I removed the "r" and "excel" tags.  Feel free to tag with the tool you are actually using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm agnostic in terms of the clean-up project - if it's easier to accomplish via excel or open refine or whatever I'm happy to do so

Comment: Which version of Joe Smith should the new value be and why?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  ie MySQL, SQL Server

Comment: Lets say you fix the table eventually. What will you do when someone gets married and changes their last name- or legally changes their name to something different?  Is the solution to update the entire table again?

Answer (score 2):

Option A: Update your table with the newest name per ID:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Name = B.Name
FROM YourTable A
JOIN (SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) RN
      FROM YourTable) B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.RN = 1
```

Option B: Alter your report to join back to the table to get the latest name per id. Here is one way:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.Name, SUM(Transaction) TotalForTheYear
FROM YourTable A
JOIN (SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) RN
      FROM YourTable) B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.RN = 1
GROUP BY A.ID, B.Name
```

These use `ROW_NUMBER()` which is not available in all DBMS (MySQL primarily).  There are other ways to write it if `ROW_NUMBER()` is unavailable.  Also the `UPDATE` syntax may vary.  Always tag or mention your DBMS options in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on the assumption that you want to set to the name that has the space and there are only the two name variants for each ID that you have outlined in your post. It also assumes MS SQL Server as no DBMS is tagged

If you want to use the name without the space, change `>0` to `=0` in the `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE  your_table
SET     your_table.Name = a.Name
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    ID,
                    Name
            FROM    your_table
        ) a
WHERE   CHARINDEX(' ', a.Name) > 0 AND
        your_table.ID = a.ID
```

I suggest you test this on a copy of your table

Answer (score 1):

While you can update the data, a better approach would appear to be fixing your database so the name lives with the ID once and only once.  You should then remove the name from the transactions table and join back to the entity with the name. I realise that might not be practical but it is more correct than fixing up denormalised data